# Set main frame not resizable

Tags: java, swing, resizable

I want to set my main frame (whole application) not resizable by the user.  Can anyone tell me how to do it?

When I set minimum and maximum size in layout design it does not work.  I'm still able to resize the whole application.

Comment: **Why** don't you want the user to allow resizing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you are using Swing and a `JFrame`, call [`setResizable(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setResizable%28boolean%29).

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).  +1 BTW